# Visual Studio 2019 post-build event

Tags: visual-studio

I need to start an external process when project debug starts.
I've wrote these lines in "Post-build event command line":

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (
  powershell start-process node "C:\Sviluppo\nodejs\index.js"
)
```

but this starts node everytime I compile the solution (in debug mode). I would like to start it only if application starts, not at compiling time.
I wouldn't like to use `Process.start`, if possible.

Comment: Why are you trying to use post-build event if you want to execute a piece of code when the program is starting? Just add that logic in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is essentially a "pre-debug" command, you should add it to `Configuration Properties > Debugging > Command`. Probably easiest to have Powershell also start your `$TargetPath`

There's no point in the `if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug` test if you simply add the command to only the Configuration=Debug settings.